# Custom geometry for a first chapter page?

Tags: floats, header-footer, margins, fancyhdr, geometry

On normal pages I have header and no footer. On first chapter page -- I have footer (with page number) and no header. Hence I need:

```
\newgeometry{top=2cm, bottom=1.2cm, left=1.5cm, right=1.7cm}
```

for normal pages, and

```
\newgeometry{top=1.2cm, bottom=2cm, left=1.5cm, right=1.7cm}
```

for first chapter page.

In the book document class the first chapter page is of the `plain` page style. I thought I could do something like:

```
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=1.2cm, left=1.5cm, right=1.7cm]{geometry}
\newcommand\pagewithheader{
  \newgeometry{top=2cm, bottom=1.2cm, left=1.5cm, right=1.7cm}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.6pt}
}
\newcommand\pagewithfooter{
  \newgeometry{top=1.2cm, bottom=1cm, left=1.5cm, right=1.7cm}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
}

\usepackage{afterpage}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \pagewithfooter
  \afterpage{\pagewithheader}
}
```

But I get all links messed up and floats gone mad. I tried to build an MWE:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,twoside]{book}

\usepackage{fontspec} % enagles loading of OpenType fonts
\usepackage{polyglossia} % support for languages

% fonts:
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text} % without this XeLaTeX won't turn "--" into dashes
\setmainfont{Arial}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=1.2cm, left=1.5cm, right=1.7cm]{geometry}
\newcommand\pagewithheader{
  \newgeometry{top=2cm, bottom=1.2cm, left=1.5cm, right=1.7cm}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.6pt}
}
\newcommand\pagewithfooter{
  \newgeometry{top=1.2cm, bottom=1cm, left=1.5cm, right=1.7cm}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
% page style for a non-chapter pages:
\renewcommand{\rightmark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\leftmark}[1]{\chaptername{}\thechapter}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LO]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{afterpage}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \pagewithfooter
  \afterpage{\pagewithheader}
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{foo}

\kant[1-12]

\chapter{bar}

\kant[1-12]

\chapter{baz}

\kant[1-12]

\end{document}
```

But unforunetly it works. While I have a complex document with tens of links and floats -- and it doesn't (I think because of floats).

What could it be? Perhaps somebody have a recipe to make the first chapter page to be of different geometry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use the scrbook class, and then `\chapterheadstartvskip` to move the `\chapter` up and `\enlargethispage` to shorten the page. Your `\leftmark` and `\rightmark` definition are nonsense, so I change them too.

```
\documentclass[a5paper,twoside]{scrbook}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=1.2cm, left=1.5cm, right=1.7cm,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

%\renewcommand{\rightmark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}} %Nonsense
%\renewcommand{\leftmark}[1]{\chaptername{}\thechapter}%nonsense

\renewcommand\chaptermark{\markboth{\chaptername{}\thechapter}{}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LO]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace{-1cm}\enlargethispage{-1cm}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{foo}

\kant[1-12]


\chapter{bar}

\kant[1-12]

\chapter{baz}

\kant[1-12]

\end{document}
```

Comment: But in Your example I don't get the page number in the footer of the first chapter page. Not even with `\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
}`.

Comment: The footer is outside the page. Either make `bottom` larger, or use a smaller `footskip`, e.g. `footskip=0.5cm`.

Answer (score 1):

There is much easier solution for that (from [wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout#Top_margin_above_Chapter))

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-50pt}{20pt}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! Feel free to visit our [TeX.SX starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to get the most out of the site.